# Blank page after Redirect::to() in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I read a lot about the Blank Page after `Redirect::to()` in Laravel 4.2. Here is my controller function:

```
public function profile($salon_id){
        $salon_profile = $this->mSalon->getSalon($salon_id);

        if(Session::get("user_type.dist_content_filter") && Session::get("user.distributor_id")!=$salon_profile["distributor_id"]){
            return Redirect::to('error/401');
        }

        $lstDistributors = $this->mDistributor->getDistributors(array());
        $lstCountries = (new Countries)->getCountries();

        View::share('lstCountries', $lstCountries);
        View::share('lstDistributors', $lstDistributors);
        View::share('salon_profile', $salon_profile);

        if(Session::get('success')){
            View::share('box_message', array("type"=>"Success","message"=>"Distributor saved successfully"));
        }

        self::setCSS("header",Config::get('cdn.css_path') . "datepicker.css");      
        self::setJS("footer",Config::get('cdn.js_path') . "jquery.validate.min.js");
        self::setJS("footer",Config::get('cdn.js_path') . "date-time/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js");
        self::setJS("footer",Config::get('cdn.js_path') . "jquery.maskedinput.min.js");

        echo View::make('common/header');
        echo View::make('salon/profile');
        echo View::make('common/footer');
    }
```

My route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'error'), function(){
    Route::get('/{error_number}', 'ErrorController@showError');
});
```

Can someone help me why I getting the Blank Page?

Thanks,

Gustavo

Comment: remove the first '/' in the Redirect::to() and try...

If not, show us your controller code

Comment: I removed and still the same problem.

Question update with my controller method

Comment: is there any route having one argument with same prefix in your application?

Comment: no, only the route that I mentioned. I'm using the same redirect in my filter. I don't know why only in this page the same redirect doesn't work.

Comment: Open up "developer tools" (in chrome) and see what you get, do you get 500? or you get 200 and some data is actually loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was my mistake. The routs for this profile don't call direct the profile method:

```
Route::get('/{action}/{object_id}', 'SalonController@action');
```

So, in my Controller I have (the wrong solution):

```
public function action($action, $object_id = null){
    if(method_exists($this,$action)){
        $this->$action($object_id);
    }else{
        return App::missing();
    }}
```

Correct solution:

```
public function action($action, $object_id = null){
if(method_exists($this,$action)){
    return $this->$action($object_id);
}else{
    return App::missing();
}}
```

I needed to include the return in the line: `$this->$action.....`

Thanks